# Spring/Hibernate Logging to Console & Not to Log File

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, log4j, slf4j

Spring MVC, Hibernate, Log4j, SLF4j

The log entries that I call are working fine. But the log entries generated by Hibernate are coming up in console, but not on the Log file.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL

log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE, console
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a logger appender like so:

```
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.File=logFileName.log
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x :: %m%n
```

Then in your log4j.rootLogger you can do

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE, MyFileAppender
```

This will put the log output into the file name specified in log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.File=logFileName.log

This will need to be added to your log4j.properties.

@Edit:

For Hibernate you need the following in your log4j.properties to identify the hibernate log categories

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, MyFileAppender
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
```

Comment: log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=applog.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
this is my complete log file.though, i have all the required configuration, the hibernate generated log statements are printed in console as System.out.Need those in the file as well.

Comment: Try the following in your log4j.properties


log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, FILE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

Comment: The Database access code is in a seperate jar and its copied to WEB-INf/lib. The webapp has all the log configurations. For some reason, the hibernate logs are printed as SystemOut in console and only the custom logs are coming up in the log file.

Comment: The problem is that i didnt have 'jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar' in my classpath. Fixed it. Thanks !!

Comment: @bsimic any way to do the same for log4j2?